# How to use PHP for selecting from two different tables, making variables from results and do math on them

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm creating a localhost webservice just for myself, while learning PHP and using SQL with it. It's a about tracking my sports data and history.

Currently I'm stuck at calculating BMI. I figured out how to calculate it when user weight and height are in the same table. It didn't take long for me to realize that my height is not going to change anytime soon, so I figured I should probably stick it in different table where other user account information is, where values never changes.

So I have only two tables so far, 'users' for user accounts and 'stats' for stuff like weight and other stuff that changes over the time.

I don't know where to start at selecting the values from different tables, making variables from weight and height and then properly do the math on them.

The code below works when using single table. It's a bit stupid right now with WHILE but LIMIT 1 because I don't know yet if I want more than one result.

Thanks in advance. Also if this code below is shit from start to end, please tell me what's wrong and how should I change it. Just learning.

EDIT: I got a question about tables structure and while I'm at work I'm just improvising since I don't have access to the actual database.

Table **users**
Columns: id - username - height

Table **stats**
Columns: id - userid (same id as 'id' in users) - weight

```
<?php
    if (!link) {
        echo "MySQL link error.";
    }

    $sql = "SELECT weight, height FROM stats WHERE userid=('$currentUserId') ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
    $result = $link->query($sql);

    if ($result = '0') {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

            $mass = $row["weight"];
            $height = $row["height"];

            function bmi($mass, $height) {
                $bmi = $mass / ($height * $height);
                return $bmi;
            }

            $bmi = bmi($mass, $height);
            echo "BMI: $bmi";
    }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
?>
```

Comment: my suggestion is to use php data objects. https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: can you share your table structure with data.

Comment: You need to do a join, you should have a column in your stats table that has the user id the stats belong to then you can join the tables on that - there are loads of tutorials about mysql joins so a quick Google should set you on the right path.  Also if you are learning then you should find a tutorial on PDO and prepared statements and start again - there's not really any excuse for injecting variables straight into mysql these days. Also, unless you have more than 1 row for the user then the order by is a bit redundant

Comment: JOIN the tables in your sql statment: "SELECT s.weight, u.height FROM users as u JOIN 
stats as s ON u.userid = s.userid
WHERE u.userid='{$currentUserId}' 
ORDER BY u.userid DESC LIMIT 1";

Answer (score 0):

For that you could use `UNION`, which would allow you to query data from different tables, your query would look something like :

```sql
select 
  u.name, 
  u.height,
  s.weight,
  u.height / (s.weight * s.weight) as bmi
from 
  users as u
  inner join stats as s 
    on stats.user_id = users.user_id
```

Note how `users` is *joined* to `stats` using the *foreign key* `user_id`.

That means that your users rows must have an id, and your stats rows must also have the user id, so they can be linked to the user they belong to.

See this for more information on `UNION` :
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html